# Rank growth of elliptic curve $E:y^2=x^3-17$ in quadratic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E:y^2=x^3-17$ be an elliptic curve.

It is known that rank$(E/\Bbb{Q})=0$.

(For example, prop $6.5$, $362$p in Silverman's book 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves')

> Over $K=\Bbb{Q}(i)$, what is the rank of $E$ ?

I couldn't find this curve ($E/\Bbb{Q}(i)$) in LMFDB
(I don't know what is known about the rank over number fields except for $\Bbb{Q}$)

Comment: $r(E/\mathbb{Q}(i)) = r(E/\mathbb{Q}) + r(E^{(-1)}/\mathbb{Q}) = 0 + 2$ with the quadratic twist $E^{(-1)}$ by $-1$.

Comment: Could you tell me why your $=$ holds  and $r(E^{(-1)}//\Bbb{Q})=2$? (Can you apply the same way to another quadratic field, for example, $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: $=$ is a general statement about quadratic twists, [Silverman 2nd ed, exercise 10.16]. I computed the rank of the twisted curve using Magma: Rank(QuadraticTwist(E,-1));

Comment: Thank you very much. Let $D \in \Bbb{Q}^{\times}$, $E_D$ be quadratic twist of $E/\Bbb{Q}$. I also used Magma to calculate rank of  $E_D(\Bbb{Q})$ for some $D$, and the result is always $2$. Possibly we can say  rank of quadratic twist is always $2$ in this elliptic curve ?

Comment: No, the rank of the quadratic twist by $-47$ is $1$. I found it using HeegnerDiscriminants(E,1,100);